# Sum of arctangents

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

How can I get the sum of two arctangents that is not restricted to the range of $(-\pi, \pi]$?$$ \arctan\Bigl(\frac{y_1}{x_1}\Bigr) + \arctan\Bigl(\frac{y_2}{x_2}\Bigr) $$
I use $\operatorname{arctan2}(y,x)$ function for calculating the above arctangent function.
I know that there is this 
$$\arctan u + \arctan v=\arctan\Bigl(\frac{u+v}{1−uv}\Bigr)$$ but it does not return the correct value for any x and y.

Comment: compute the summands and add?

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen I'm looking for one formula. The value of x and y are changing over the time in my program.

Comment: the sum is only valid in the principal branch.  Otherwise it's valid modulo $\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo $\pi$, we have
$$\begin{align}\arctan\frac{y_1}{x_1}+\arctan\frac{y_2}{x_2}&=\arg(x_1+iy_1)+\arg(x_2+iy_2)\\
&=\arg\bigl((x_1+iy_1)(x_2+iy_2)\bigr)\\
&=\arg\bigl((x_1x_2-y_1y_2)+i(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)\bigr)\\
&=\arctan\frac{x_1y_2+x_2y_1}{x_1x_2-y_1y_2}\end{align}. $$
In order to cope with the possible error by multiples of $\pi$, it suffices to compute the original $\arctan$s *very* roughly (note that an error of $\pm.75$ per summand would not hurt!); in fact, just looking at the quadrants (i.e., signs of the $x_i,y_i$) is precise enough ...

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen I need to find some conditions to get the sum from arctan[(x1y2+x2y1)/(x1x2−y1y2)] by considering four quadrants.